# Is it necessary to use extension for delegate method definition in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, swift2

Is it necessary to use extension for delegate method definition in swift ?

Eg:

```
extension MasterViewController: DetailViewControllerDelegate {
   func didFinishTask(sender: DetailViewController) 
   { 
    // do stuff like updating the UI 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Eg:
extension MasterViewController: DetailViewControllerDelegate {
  func didFinishTask(sender: DetailViewController) {
    // do stuff like updating the UI
  }
}

Comment: No. You don't need to use an extension

Comment: What do you think? Have you tried this with and without an extension? What happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it not necessary to implement delegate methods in extension only. you can implement delegate methods to simple view controller to which delegate is confirm.

e.g

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
     override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

     }

     // MARK: Image Picker Controller Delegate method

     func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I have seen usage of extension for delegate methods definition,when should we use extension for delegate method definition? Is there any specific case?